# creating a list of list for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This my code:

```
num= [2,10]

def calculo(lista):
    lista2 = []    
    for i in lista:
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            if i % j == 0:
                lista2.append(j)
    return lista2

print(calculo(num))
```

Which produces: `[1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 10].` However, I need the following result:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 5, 10]]
```

In addition, I would like to know your approach through list comprehension.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got downvoted even if there's a duplicate out there, which I'm too lazy to find, this seems like a fairly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will foreach `i` loop append new list and then append new values to the last list

```py
num= [2,10]

def calculo(lista):
    lista2 = []    
    for i in lista:
        lista2.append([])
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            if i % j == 0:
                lista2[-1].append(j)
    return lista2

print(calculo(num))
```

Also in short form:

```py
num= [2,10]

def calculo(lista):
    lista2 = [[j for j in range(1, i+1) if i % j == 0] for i in lista]
    return lista2

print(calculo(num))
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new list for every iteration of the loop:

```
outer_list = []
for i in lista:
    inner_list = []
    for j in range(...):
        if ...:
            inner_list.append(...)
    outer_list.append(inner_list)
return outer_list
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use list comprehension

```
[[x for x in range(1, n+1) if n%x==0] for n in num]
```

Comment: This is not the same as OP's loop.

Comment: Did you actually run it?

Comment: Yes I did. Enumerate wasn't necessary but besides that it should be fine or not?

Comment: Should be fine. Enumerate was the problem. Please fix

Comment: I edited the answer, however it also worked before :)

Comment: Vote flipped. It certainly didn't work with the enumeration. Your range was 1-2 for the second element, not 1-10

Answer (score 1):

```
num = [2,10]

def calculo(lista):
    result = [[j for j in range(1, i + 1) if i % j == 0] for i in lista]
    return result

print(calculo(num))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 5, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the nested lists before the nested loop, just like you make the outer list before the outer loop:

```
num = [2,10]

def calculo(lista):
    lista2 = []    
    for i in lista:
        lista3 = []
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            if i % j == 0:
                lista3.append(j)
        if lista3:
            lista2.append(lista3)
    return lista2

print(calculo(num))
```

Any time you have a sufficiently simple loop that appends items to a list, you can turn it into a list comprehension. For example, the inner loop becomes:

```
lista3 = [j for j in range(1, i + 1) if i % j == 0]
```

Now you can write the entire function as:

```
def calculo(lista):
    return [[j for j in range(1, i + 1) if i % j == 0] for i in lista]
```